# why the Items in QlistWidget keep the focusing on it once the user select one of the Item

Tags: python, path, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a code that display Items in a QlistWidget that refer to a **file path** once the user select one of the items the system display its content.

The problem is that once the user select one of the item it keep the focus on it and the user can't select other item.

**the Image below show that both items have focus that mean when i try to select the second Item i must deselect the first and vise versa.**

[image]

How to fix this?

example :

- C:\Users\test\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.docx row =>0
- C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx                 row =>1

the displayed result on the console :

> current row = 0 this is P==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx
>   this is oneDir==>C:\Users\test this is the cuurent Item
>   ==C:\Users\test\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.docx
>
> current row = 1 this is P==>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx
>   this is oneDir==>C:\Users\test this is the cuurent Item
>   ==C:\Users\test\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.docx

and if the user select twice the same item the system display this error :

> mouseHover   toolTipResult = self.listWidgetPDFlist.setToolTip(Item)
>
> builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Item' referenced before
>   assignment

## code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QMimeData)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QMenu,QListWidgetItem)

#from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pdfviewer
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import os
import re
from os import path
import json,datetime,time
from collections import defaultdict

import docx

import PyPDF2


class pdfViewer(pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow):

    def __init__(self,PdfPreviewObj):
        pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow.__init__(self)

        self.PdfPreviewObj =PdfPreviewObj 
        self.setupUi(PdfPreviewObj)
        self.PdfPreviewObj.show()

        '''
        buttons status at the init of the program
        '''
        self.pushButtonSearch.setEnabled(False)    
        rMyIcon = QtGui.QPixmap("checkBox.ico");
        self.SelectAll.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(rMyIcon))
        self.SelectAll.setEnabled(False)


        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.clicked.connect(self.openfolder)
        self.ExportButton.clicked.connect(self.openExport)        
        self.pushButtonSearch.clicked.connect(self.FilteredListSearch)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.clicked.connect(self.MatchFunc)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.doubleClicked.connect(self.OpenTheSelectedFile)
        #self.NewClearList.clicked.connect(self.NewClearListFN)
        self.SelectAll.clicked.connect(self.selectAllFN)

    def mouseHover(self):
        p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath) 
        print("MouseHover this is P==>{}".format(p))
        oneDir = os.path.join(*p.parts[:-2])
        print("MouseHover this is oneDir==>{}".format(oneDir))  

        if self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems():
            Item = oneDir + "\\" + self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[0].text()
            print("MouseHover this is the cuurent Item =={}".format(Item))   

        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setStyleSheet("""QToolTip { 
                                   background-color: black; 
                                   color: white;                            
                                   border-radius: 10px;
                                   border: black solid 1px;
                                   font: 12px
                                   }""")

        print("current row = {}".format(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentRow()))

        toolTipResult = self.listWidgetPDFlist.setToolTip(Item)
        return toolTipResult

    def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane
        self.mouseHover()
        p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath) 
        print("this is P==>{}".format(p))
        oneDir = os.path.join(*p.parts[:-2])
        print("this is oneDir==>{}".format(oneDir))  

        if self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems():
            Item = oneDir + "\\" + self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[0].text()
            print("this is the cuurent Item =={}".format(Item))   
            return Item

        else:
            print("<b>!!! NO SELECTED FILE !!!</b>\n")

 def checkPath(self,folder):         # Funtion to check the given path for the wanted extension (Files)

        try:
            directory=folder

            whichChecked=""
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

                for filename in files:
                    if len(self.lineEdit_Ext.text())>0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("Enter The Filetype Extention Here")

                        if filename.endswith(self.lineEdit_Ext.text()):
                            fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                            print(fullPath)
                            self.fileList.append(fullPath)

                    elif self.rdBtn_txt.isChecked() and filename.endswith("txt"):
                        fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                        self.fileList.append(fullPath)
                        whichChecked="txt Ext was Selected"


                    elif self.rdBtn_pdf.isChecked() and filename.endswith("pdf"):
                        fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                        self.fileList.append(fullPath)
                        whichChecked="pdf Ext was Selected"
                    elif self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked() and filename.endswith("docx") or filename.endswith("doc") :
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)

                        p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath)
                        oneDir = os.path.join(*p.parts[-2:])                    
                        self.fileList.append(oneDir)                        
                        #self.fileList.append(self.fullPath)
                        whichChecked="docx - doc Ext was Selected"

                    if len(self.fileList) > 0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("bacground-color:white;")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("{0}".format(whichChecked))
                    else:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:Red")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("No Ext is Specified")                            


            self.ListFilesInViewer(self.fileList)           # add the list into the  listWidgetPDFlist 
            self.pushButtonSearch.setEnabled(True)
            self.SelectAll.setEnabled(True)

            return folder

        except Exception as e:
            print("this error occure {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: You've not included your pdfviewer ui file to make this a runnable example, but from your selection description I'd guess you have listWidgetPDFlist set to selectionMode MultipleSelection where you want SingleSelection.

Comment: yes you were right thank you. make your comment as an answer to upvote for you

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you have listWidgetPDFlist set to selectionMode MultipleSelection where you want SingleSelection.  This can be changed in Qt Designer or via code as the following example shows.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    for i in range(10):
        w.addItem('Item {}'.format(i))
    # w.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)  # Multiple selection via control key        
    # w.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)  # Multiple selection (click toggle)
    w.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)  # Single selection
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```